# No write permissions on samba share

Tags: samba, network-share, fedora

I created a samba network share on a Fedora VM, from a windows machine I can access the share in read only, I can't write on the share.
The configuration of the share is:

```
[net_share]
    comment = share for family data
    path = /var/net_share
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    write list = giulio
    valid users = @net_share
```

Samba's global configuration is as follows:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
```

The permissions on the folder:

```
drwxrwx---.  3 giulio net_share   36 20 mar 20.50 net_share
```

user `giulio` groups:

```
giulio : giulio net_share
```

`net_share` group:

```
net_share:x:1001:giulio
```

From what I've seen in the Internet the configuration should be fine but it still doesn't give me write permissions. Does someone know the issue?

Comment: try `force group = net_share`  since you did not use the origin user to access it

Comment: The folder has extended attributes. Use `getfacl` to check the ACL.

Comment: adding force group didn't solve the problem unfortunately, and no ACL is applied:
# file: net_share/
# owner: giulio
# group: net_share
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---

Comment: Giulio please add detail to your question where you can format it and make it easy to find. Help us to help you

Comment: I'm sorry Davies, I'm new to the platform and I don't know how to format text in form of code, I tried with ' and ''' but it didn't work